# Reading Network Traffic

Tags: network-programming

I want to intercept all network traffic coming and going from a specific application on a Windows XP. How do I get started doing this?

The goal would be to reverse engineer the API used between the local software and the remote software and implement the same API in my own software package.

I can program in anything, Java is the easiest however.

Comment: To get all network traffic you could a tool called WireShark for example

Comment: http://www.winpcap.org/windump/default.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), no need of programming anything.